# this.nameOfFunction is not a function when calling it

Tags: react-native

I have made an alert message in react native and when click it calls a function. But I have the error message:

> _this.function1 is not a function.(In '_this.goToMapBack('1')', '_this.goToMapBack' is undefined)

```
  alertFunction(){
    Alert.alert(
      "Text Message",
      [
        {
          text: 'Yes',
          onPress: this.function1('1'),
        },
        {
          text: 'No',
          onPress: this.function1('2'),
        },
      ],
      {cancelable: false},
    );
  }

  function1(value){
    if (value =='1') {
      var url = "XXXXX";
    }
    else{
      var url = "YYYYY"
    }
    Linking.openURL(url);
  }

  render() {
    const valueNb = navigation.getParam('valNb', '1');
    return (
        <View>
                <Button
                      onPress={this.alertFunction.bind(valueNb)}
                      title="qwerty"
                      color="#ffffff"
                    />
```

I have also tested **onPress: function1('1')**, **onPress: () => this.function1('1')** but function is always undefined.

Do you know how to correct it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your anonymous function into arrow function to get `this` context:

> Arrow function is automatically bound to its parent (You don't need to
>   bind it explicity) ... cause it doesn't have **it's own context**

```
class Comp {
  alertFunction = () => {
    Alert.alert(
      "Text Message",
      [
        {
          text: "Yes",
          onPress: this.function1("1")
        },
        {
          text: "No",
          onPress: this.function1("2")
        }
      ],
      { cancelable: false }
    );
  };

  function1 = value => {
    if (value == "1") {
      var url = "XXXXX";
    } else {
      var url = "YYYYY";
    }
    Linking.openURL(url);
  };

  render() {
    const valueNb = navigation.getParam("valNb", "1");
    return (
      <View>
        <Button onPress={this.alertFunction} title="qwerty" color="#ffffff" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**If you choose to use anonymous function**

You need to bind your function in the constructor ... cause **Anonymous Function** has it's own context ... that's why you need to tell it to use the `this` context of your component instead

> You could bind your anonymouns function when you pass it to your on
>   Press . but it's not recommended, cause it's going to create a new
>   copy of your function each time it's invoked

```
class Comp {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.function1 = this.function1.bind(this);
    this.alertFunction = this.alertFunction.bind(this);
  }

  alertFunction() {
    Alert.alert(
      "Text Message",
      [
        {
          text: "Yes",
          onPress: this.function1("1")
        },
        {
          text: "No",
          onPress: this.function1("2")
        }
      ],
      { cancelable: false }
    );
  }

  function1(value) {
    if (value == "1") {
      var url = "XXXXX";
    } else {
      var url = "YYYYY";
    }
    Linking.openURL(url);
  }

  render() {
    const valueNb = navigation.getParam("valNb", "1");
    return (
      <View>
        <Button onPress={this.alertFunction} title="qwerty" color="#ffffff" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It works: Can you explaain me why it didn't work ? The function was evaluated when the component was mounted, so the function wasn't recognized ?